# interpreting object addresses with reintepret_cast

Tags: c++, casting

The following code gives the output as 136. But I could not understand how the first two address comparisons are equal. Appreciate any help to understand this. Thank you.

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
public:
    A() : m_i(0){ }
protected:
    int m_i;
};

class B
{
public:
    B() : m_d(0.0) { }
protected:
    double m_d;
};

class C : public A, public B
{
public:
    C() : m_c('a') { }
private:
    char m_c;
};

int main( )
{
 C d;
 A *b1 = &d;
 B *b2 = &d;

const int a = (reinterpret_cast<char *>(b1) == reinterpret_cast<char *>(&d)) ? 1 : 2;
const int b = (b2 == &d) ? 3 : 4;
const int c = (reinterpret_cast<char *>(b1) == reinterpret_cast<char *>(b2)) ? 5 : 6;

std::cout << a << b << c << std::endl;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `reinterpret_cast` here? What do you expect from using `char*` for a pointer type on your architecture?

Comment: this is not from a real-time application. This was from a C++ test. I just want to understand how reinterpret_cast is interpreting the addresses in this specific case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use multiple inheritance like in your example the first base class and the derived class share the same base address. Additional classes you inherit from are arranged in order at an offset based on the size of all preceding classes. The result of the comparison is true because the base address of `d` and `b1` are the same.

In your case, if the size of `A` is 4 bytes then `B` will start at base address of `A` + 4 bytes. When you do `B *b2 = &d;` the compiler calculates the offset and adjusts the pointer value accordingly.

When you do `b2 == &d` an implicit conversion from type 'C' to type 'B' is performed on `d` before the comparison is done. This conversion adjusts the offset of the pointer value just as it would in an assignment.

Comment: Updated the answer to include info on why that results in true

Answer (score 0):

It’s pretty typical for a derived class (like `C` here) to be laid out in memory so it starts with its two base classes (`A` and `B`), so the address of an instance of type `C` would be identical to the address of the instance its first base class (i.e. `A`).

Answer (score 0):

In this kind of inheritance (when `virtual` is not involved,) each instance of `C` will have the following layout:

- First, there will be all members of `A` (which is just `m_i`, a 4-byte integer)
- Second will be all members of `B` (which is just `m_d`, an 8-byte double)
- Last will be all members of `C` itself, which is just a character (1 byte, `m_c`)

When you cast a pointer to an instance of `C` to `A`, because `A` is the first parent, no address adjustment takes place, and the numerical value of the two pointers will be the same. This is why the first comparison evaluates to `true`. (Note that doing a `reinterpret_cast<char *>()` on a pointer never causes adjustment, so it always gives the numerical value of the pointer. Casting to `void *` would have the same effect and is probably safer for comparison.)

Casting a pointer to an instance of `C` to `B` *will* cause a pointer adjustment (by 4 bytes) which means that the numerical value of `b2` will *not* be equal to `&d`. However, when you directly compare `b2` and `&d`, the compiler automatically generates a cast for `&d` to `B *`, which will adjust the numerical value by 4 bytes. This is the reason that the second comparison also evaluates to `true`.

The third comparison return `false` because, as said before, casting a pointer to an instance of `C` to `A` or to `B` will have different results (casting to `A *` doesn't do adjustment, while casting to `B *` does.)

Comment: The layout is compiler-dependent. What you have described is typical but it isn't mandated anywhere.

Comment: @EJP Right you are! But the OP was asking for someone to explain the behavior he is seeing on his compiled code. And I was doing just that. I'm not claiming that this is mandated by the standard; I'm just explaining how the output of his program came to be what it is.